# Key-pair management for build server EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, key-pair

I am working on bringing a bit of devops sanity to my environment. Until now, we've all been building releases on our local systems and then scp`ing these builds to the target EC2 instances. This is not ideal for these reasons:

- I want to build on Linux, not on BSD, if I my target environment is Linux.
- I don't want any local environment idiosyncrasies to get in the way, and I don't want to be in the business of policing developers' local environments.
- Transferring builds between EC2 VMs is instantaneous, but takes potentially long time transferring from our locals systems, which are frequently on a slow public WiFi.

I have an devops AMI, that can be launched by a developer, which has all the tooling to build the product distro. The next step is for the developer to transfer that distro to another EC2 "target" EC2 instance, where it can be unpacked and run. And it's this scp hop from the build to the target instance that I am struggling with. My solutions, as I see them are:

- Make each developer copy their private key to the build machine. Then, assuming that the target instance was started by the same developer, sch will be happy.
- Have a shared key-pair, call it "devops". This way, I can pre-install the private key on the build AMI, and, so long as developers launch both build and target instances with those keys, everything will be transparent.

Both have their shortcomings, so I wonder what's the best practice here.

Comment: Wouldn't the normal practice be that they should check-in their code to a git repository, then the build should be an automated process that pulls the desired release and activates the build? This way, it is also testing the Prod release process.

Comment: The build pipeline is operational, but it doesn't build a production release. Perhaps it should, but I don't see how that wold solve my problem.

Comment: Personal private keys shouldn't be copied anywhere.  If you want to transfer files from host to host establish an s3 bucket and use server roles to access it.  Look at using SSM or AWS Secrets to manage it if you really want to use a shared keypair